# getting thumbnail images from saved path of video files in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video

I am trying to display thumbnail images for the downloaded videos in one of my apps. I have shown the images along with the video title inside a table view. I'm using this code for getting the image:

```
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myString];
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] 
    initWithContentURL:videoURL];

UIImage *thumbnail = 
    [player thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 
                      timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];      
cell.imageView.image = thumbnail;`
```

Images are showing for the files that are downloaded from YouTube, but I'm not getting the images from .flv video files. Can anyone suggest a solution? This is a sample of my video path

```
/Users/admin/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/AA8DDEED-E91C-47BB-8F1E-C057D9E94B7C/Documents/downloads/qkycmzafawmk.flv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the tutorial i have followed to solve this issue.Hope this may help someone: http://www.codza.com/extracting-frames-from-movies-on-iphone.

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of `thumbnail` after the call to `-thumbnailImageAtTime:timeOption:`?  Assuming that this `UIImage` is not `nil`, have you checked its `alpha` property?

If `thumbnail` is `nil`, have you checked into the numerous other SO questions regarding this?  Here are a couple to get you started:

- [MPMoviePlayerControlle thumbnailImageAtTime: timeOption: giving
  empty UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178631/mpmovieplayercontrolle-thumbnailimageattime-timeoption-giving-empty-uiimage)
- [MPMoviePlayerController
  thumbnailImageAtTime:timeOption: simple case doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496757/mpmovieplayercontroller-thumbnailimageattimetimeoption-simple-case-doesnt-wor)

Comment: thumbnail image is nil.also he images are shown for .mov files

Comment: in the case of .mov files, images are getting in the thumbnail

Comment: Also, are results different if you specify an exact time, instead of using `MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame`?

Comment: i tried your suggested answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178631/mpmovieplayercontrolle-thumbnailimageattime-timeoption-giving-empty-uiimage.but it is not entering in this condition AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler handler = ^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef im, CMTime actualTime, AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error){}

Comment: Sorry about the delay.  So, did you fix the problem I general, or just the problem with that block?

Comment: i changed the code according to the tutorial that i have put as answer below.